# c# hash through multiple files

Tags: c#, hash, filestream

I am having an problem with some code, that I would like to use for hashing multiple files. I am using wpf in visual studio and the code is as follows:

```
    public string checkMD5(string filename)
    {
        string output;

        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length);

                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                }
                output = filename + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        return output;

    }
```

The problem is, it is being fed a list of multiple filenames in the form of
C://file1
C://file2
C://file3

Code executes 1 filename just fine. How do I make the above loop through this list of filenames? Any help is much appreciated.. I have been at this for two days now :(

Comment: Have you tried calling your `checkMD5()` in a foreach loop?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you actually need help with? The `String.Split()` method will take a single `string` instance and divide it according to whatever delimiter you specify, e.g. spaces (`' '`). Did you try that? Please fix your question so it includes a proper [mcve] that shows exactly what you've tried, explain exactly what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: I have tried several methods to split the string being fed into the checkmd5 function but they all result in the same error, caught by an error handler. shows up as System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at WpfApp1.MainWindow.runButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.Split() to split them, then just loop through each one:

```
string[] individualFileNames = filename.Split(' ');
foreach(string individualFileName in individualFileNames)
{
   // open and process file individualFileName here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want a string array with the file names and then have a simple `for` or `foreach` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNameArray.Length; i++)
{
    string output = checkMD5(fileNameArray[i]);
}

or

foreach (string fileName in fileNameArray)
{
    string output = checkMD5(fileName);
}
```

To get a array of file names from a directory you can use the function [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0).

Considering that you said the function is `being fed a list of multiple filenames in the form of C://file1 C://file2 C://file3` I am going to assume that the file names are in a single string, if that's the case you will have to figure out a way to split it into an array of file names and then pass each one to the function as above, to do this you can try use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) like so:

```
string fileNames = "C://file1 C://file2 C://file3";

string[] fileNameArray = fileNames.Split(' ');

//fileNameArray[0] > C://file1

//fileNameArray[1] > C://file2

//fileNameArray[2] > C://file3

foreach (...)
```

Keep in mind that if any of the file names have spaces in their paths then this won't work, e.g.:

```
string fileNames = "C://Some Files//file1 C://file2 C://file3";

string[] fileNameArray = fileNames.Split(' ');

//fileNameArray[0] > C://Some

//fileNameArray[1] > Files//file1

//fileNameArray[2] > C://file2

//fileNameArray[3] > C://file3
```

In this example `C://Some Files//file1` would be split into 2 because the path has a space in the directory name `Some Files`.

I would recommended just using [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) to get a list of file names than anything else.